# NodeRED bluemix/IBM Cloud starter installation fails with IAM error

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

The installation of the [NodeRED bluemix/IBM Cloud starter application](https://github.com/ibmets/node-red-bluemix-starter) fails with an IAM error message complaining about insufficient rights:

`FAILED
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: You do not have the required permission to create an instance. You must be assigned the IAM Editor role or higher. Contact the account owner to update your access.`

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: That looks like a Bluemix/IBM Cloud issue rather than something you can fix yourself

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don’t have proper IAM access permission. If you are the owner of the account, you can set the required permissions following the steps in this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/bp_access.html#account_setup) .If you are not the owner ask the account owner for the permissions.

For best practices, refer this [solution tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/users-teams-applications.html#best-practices-for-organizing-users-teams-applications)

Comment: I actually have administrator rights on the resource group. The error message is misleading, the creation of the instance fails because you can create only one lite plan instance (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was actually related to the fact that the bluemix starter application tries to create a lite plan instance of cloudant. In my case, that was not possible because there already was such an instance and you are allowed only one per CF organization.

The solution was to patch the pipeline.yml to create a standard plan instance:

`cf create-service cloudantNoSQLDB Standard "${CLOUDANT_NAME}"`

Comment: I understand that most users will rather use the lite plan of Cloudant. In case you need to set up the starter application with the standard plan of Cloudant, you may use https://github.com/cgawron/node-red-bluemix-starter.